# django: is there a way to specify title for inlines

Tags: django, django-admin

I have these two model admins:

```
class SingleImageInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
  model = Image
  extra = 1
  max_num = 1
  can_delete = False


class SponsorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
      ('Basic Info', {
        'fields': ['name']
      }),
   ]
   list_display = ['name']
   search_fields = ['name']
 inlines = [SingleImageInline, ]
```

`Sponsor` has an `Image` field called `logo`. The admin form that has the `SingleImageInline` form has `Images` displayed in it's header, is there a way I could change it to say `Logo`, may be something like this?

```
inlines = [(`Logo`, SingleImageInline), ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could give a verbose_name to `SingleImageInline`:

```
class SingleImageInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
  model = Image
  extra = 1
  max_num = 1
  can_delete = False
  verbose_name = "logo"
  verbose_name_plural = "logos"
```

EDIT

subclass `SingleImageInline`, then put there the verbose_name

```
class SingleImageInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
  model = Image
  extra = 1
  max_num = 1
  can_delete = False

class SingleImageInlineOtherName(SingleimageInline):
  verbose_name = "logo"
  verbose_name_plural = "logos" # bit redundant as Django automatically adds 's' to plural names, but it's just for the purpose

class SponsorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
      ('Basic Info', {
        'fields': ['name']
      }),
   ]
   list_display = ['name']
   search_fields = ['name']
 inlines = [SingleImageInlineOtherName, ] # use the subclass here
```

Comment: please see my comment in response to Hedde

Comment: this is what I was trying to avoid, but you confirmed my suspicion that there's no easier method. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can

```
class SingleImageInline(generic.GenericTabularInline):
   model = Image
   extra = 1
   max_num = 1
   can_delete = False
   verbose_name = "Logo"
   verbose_name_plural = "Logos"
```

Comment: thank you, but this changes the name for every case, I want it to change for only one case above, in other case it works fine :-)

Comment: Just inherit the inline for your particular cases, thats better practice then monkey patching.

Comment: thanks, was trying to avoid it. you are right though, better than monkey patching